# Can not restore authentication user data from shared preferences in login activity with button and checkbox

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save in shared preferences file user's authentication data by checking the check box and when I try to restore them by clicking the  btnrestoreData it does nothing. After I introduce the data and checked the checkbox I go to main activity, but when I try to introduce it via btnrestoreData it does nothing and my checkbox remains unchecked. What should I do? I appreciate any help I will get! I am new to android!

```
LoginActivity:

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, passw;
    private Button login, restoreUserData;
    private TextView newHere;
    private CheckBox rememberMe;
    SharedPreferences shp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private FirebaseAuth authFireBase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        login = findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn);
        restoreUserData = findViewById(R.id.btnRestoreData);
        newHere = findViewById(R.id.newHere);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email3);
        passw = findViewById(R.id.password3);
        rememberMe = findViewById(R.id.chbRemember);
        authFireBase = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //Autentificare utilizator
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Preluare date existente din firebase
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginUserAccount();
            }
        });

        rememberMe.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if( compoundButton.isChecked()){

                    shp= getSharedPreferences("checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    editor = shp.edit();
                    editor.putString("rememberMe", "true");
                    editor.putString("email", email.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("password", passw.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if( !compoundButton.isChecked()){

                    shp= getSharedPreferences("checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    editor = shp.edit();
                    editor.putString("rememberMe", "false");
                    editor.putString("email", "");
                    editor.putString("password", "");
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        newHere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Cand aplicatia se deschide va cauta fisierul sharedpreferances
        SharedPreferences shp = getSharedPreferences( " checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String checkbox = shp.getString("remember", "");

//        if(checkbox.equals("true")){
//
////            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
////            startActivity(intent);
//        }else if(checkbox.equals("false")){
//
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Please log in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        }

        restoreUserData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            String prefrences = shp.getString("email", "");
            String pass = shp.getString("password", "");

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(checkbox.equals("true")){
                    email.setText(prefrences);
                    passw.setText(pass);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void loginUserAccount() {

        String emailEt = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String passwordEt = passw.getText().toString().trim();

        //Validare email, parola
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailEt)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter email!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordEt)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter password!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailEt).matches()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Provide a valid email",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(passwordEt.length() < 6)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password should be at least 6 characters!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        authFireBase.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailEt, passwordEt)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        }else{

                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                    "Failed to login! Please check your credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SP (SharedPreferences) name used in the Editor and the SP used for recovery info has a little difference (there is a space in the second one):

Your code for the onCheckedChanged method

```
shp= getSharedPreferences("checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = shp.edit();
```

Later

```
//Cand aplicatia se deschide va cauta fisierul sharedpreferances
SharedPreferences shp = getSharedPreferences( " checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Can you check if this isn't the problem?

Also, I don't see when do you save the "remember" value...